# Uploaded event on ZiggeoApi not being fired

Tags: javascript, webrtc

After looking at the ZiggeoApi [docs](https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-interaction/events#javascript-revision=v1-r20&javascript-version=v2) I attempted to use the `uploaded` event:

```
ZiggeoApi.Events.on "system_ready", ->
      recorder = ZiggeoApi.V2.Recorder.findByElement($('#ziggeo-recorder-embedding')[0])
      recorder.on "verified", (params...) ->
        console.log('uploaded', params...)
      recorder.on "uploaded", (params...) ->
        console.log('uploaded', params...)
```

In the above code, `verified` does fire, but `uploaded` does not. I'm using V2 of the API which is in beta, so I'm wondering whether this is a bug.

All I need is the video id once the video is uploaded so I have a reference to it for later retrieval. The documentation for what `data` is for each event is somewhat lacking, and for `verified` you don't actually get anything passed in as an argument when the event is fired. Any work arounds are most welcome!

Comment: I have updated my answer to include new details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v2 does not require the data parameter to pass the token as you can grab it at any point directly.

To do that you would use the code such as this:

```
recorder.get('video');
```

Also it is good to mention that as soon as the upload is started the token is already available in both v1 and v2 so you should be able to grab them even then if needed.

**EDIT 2016/11/18**

> The [JavaScript SDK](https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks) documentation pages
>   is relatively new, and the [Events
>   page](https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-interaction/events)
>   shows wrong code sample for v2 at the moment.

- This is already resolved and the Ziggeo Docs are showing correct samples.

-- end edit --

Correct way to add it would be:

```
recorder.on("uploaded", function() {
  recorder.get('video');
});
```

Adding a working sample showing both verified, uploading and uploaded events

```js
ZiggeoApi.token = "a48e03aee097e23697b165ad6060f32f";

ZiggeoApi.Events.on("system_ready", function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('ziggeo-recorder-embedding');
  var recorder = ZiggeoApi.V2.Recorder.findByElement( element );
  
  recorder.on('verified', function() {
    console.log("video was verified. It's token is:" + recorder.get('video') );
  });
  
  recorder.on('uploading', function() {
    console.log("video is uploading. It's token is:" + recorder.get('video') );
  });
  
  //Requires v1-r18 or higher to work
  recorder.on('uploaded', function() {
    console.log("video is uploaded. It's token is:" + recorder.get('video') );
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://assets-cdn.ziggeo.com/v1-r18/ziggeo.css" />
    <script src="https://assets-cdn.ziggeo.com/v1-r18/ziggeo.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ziggeorecorder
      ziggeo-width="640"
      ziggeo-height="480"
      id="ziggeo-recorder-embedding">
    </ziggeorecorder>
  </body>
</html>
```

- The snippet might not work (depending on browser and its security settings) however using the same code on localhost or some server will.
- Good to mention also that `uploaded` event does in deed not seem to work at this point - so it is a bug.

If it is in the documentation it is considered as something that should work (and was working), so if it is not, it is definitely some kind of a bug.

To summarize, you did find a bug with `uploaded` event, however for what you are after you could use `uploading` event instead as so:

```
recorder.on("uploading", function() {
  recorder.get('video');
});
```

**EDIT 2016/10/28**

The `uploaded` event was actually introduced in r18, so it should work in r18, 19 and up.

It will however not work on stable tag since it points currently to v1-r16 during which it was not available.

- I have updated the sample script above and the code on the docs page will be fixed soon as well.